# Symfony Form Collection error

Tags: php, symfony

I have two entities that are connected to each other by doctrine association many-to-one. I created a form collection but when i try to save something it hits me with an error.

The error that i'm getting:

```
Expected argument of type "Zenith\SurveyBundle\Entity\SurveyOption", "array" given
```

This is my first form the one that loads the collection.

```
class TestType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('option', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => SurveyOptionType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'entry_options' => [
                    'label' => false,
                ],
            ])
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => 'Salveaza',
            ])
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => SurveyManager::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

This is the form loaded by collection:

```
class SurveyOptionType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('isEnabled', CheckboxType::class, [
                'label' => 'Chestionar Activ',
            ])
            ->add('headquarter', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => HeadQuarterManager::class,
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => false,
            ])
            ->add('userNumber', IntegerType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'min' => '1',
                    'type' => 'number',
                ],
                'label' => 'Numar Utilizatori',
            ])
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => SurveyOption::class
        ));
    }
}
```

My Controller action:

```
   public function newAction($surveyId, Request $request)
    {
        $surveyOption = new SurveyOption();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $surveyRepository = $em->getRepository(SurveyManager::class);
        $survey = $surveyRepository->findOneBy(['id' => $surveyId]);

        $form = $this->createForm(TestType::class, $survey);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        }

        return [
            'surveyOption' => $surveyOption,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ];
    }
```

Comment: The `SurveyManager` should have a `getOptions` method, I think it is best  to rename the form field to `surveyOption` so it will never collide with the form options. Back in Symfony 2.3 another method was called "getOptions" which now is renamed to "configureOptions".

Comment: The entities have all the required methods .. because i used generatie:entities on them

Answer (score 0):

The question is useless.. because i'm a hurry and overburned .. i didn't notice few mistakes.. the forms where fine .. :-)